# How to make cryptsetup abandon a drive once password limit is reached?

Tags: boot, usb, password, encryption, cryptsetup

I would like to set up my encrypted root partition so that it can decrypt automatically if my USB flash drive with a keyfile is present, but ask for a password otherwise. There is one thing preventing me from getting it set up though: if a password entry fails (because the USB stick isn't present) cryptsetup goes into sleep.
How can I make it abandon the attempt and move onto the next line of crypttab (which is decrypting with manual password entry) instead?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried adding `nofail` as an option in `crypttab` (I've not tested this on my system)

Comment: Yes, I believe I've now tried every combination of `nofail` and `x-systemd.device-timeout` possible.
`nofail` makes no difference, the decrypt still gets stuck on the drive, it just waits for the timeout and then retries with the non-existent key, putting it into timeout again. This goes on indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Nofail isn't recognized as an option in crypttab for some versions of cryptsetup, but check and checkargs can be used to write a script see if a disk is present.  From `man crypttab`

```
   check[=<check>]
       Check the content of the target device by a suitable program; if the check fails, the device is closed immediately. The program is being run with decrypted volume (target device) as first positional
       argument and, if the checkargs option is used, its value as second argument. See the CHECKSCRIPTS section for more information.

       The program is either specified by full path or relative to /lib/cryptsetup/checks/. If omitted, then the value of $CRYPTDISKS_CHECK set in /etc/default/cryptdisks is used (blkid by default).

       This option is specific to the Debian crypttab format. It's not supported by systemd.

   checkargs=<arguments>
       Give <arguments> as the second argument to the check script. See the CHECKSCRIPTS section for more information.

       This option is specific to the Debian crypttab format. It's not supported by systemd.
```